# Inject a keystroke in java

Tags: java, keyboard, key, keystroke

I'm looking for a way to inject a keystroke into the OS keyboard input buffer, 
like when you click a button the program inserts one (or more) keyboard strokes. I wanted to do this in java because I want to run this in (win,linux and osx). I guess that I'll have to make use of the JNI, do anyone have some ideas?

Thanks all stackoverflowers ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that the java.awt.Robot class will do this for you:

```
new Robot().keyPress(...);
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#keyPress(int)

java.awt.Robot "is used to generate native system input events for the purposes of test automation, self-running demos, and other applications where control of the mouse and keyboard is needed."

Answer (score 3):

Check java [Robot](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) . I believe this is what you are looking for.

Also check this out. [Example](http://www.devdaily.com/java/java-robot-class-example-mouse-keystroke)

Comment: Welcome. Happy automation :-)